# Storybook keep in loading status for react native?

Tags: react-native, storybook

I'm following the introduction from the official website here: https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/intro-to-storybook/react-native/en/get-started/

I have repeated the steps for few times, I still can't start the storybook. Anyone success?

Any hint for what I missed?

[image]

As Tyler requested, I share the storybook index file as below (I didn't change anything, it is completed autogenerated new app):

```
import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";

import {
  getStorybookUI,
  configure,
  addDecorator,
} from "@storybook/react-native";
import { withKnobs } from "@storybook/addon-knobs";

import "./rn-addons";

// enables knobs for all stories
addDecorator(withKnobs);

// import stories
configure(() => {
  require("./stories");
}, module);

// Refer to https://github.com/storybookjs/react-native/tree/master/app/react-native#getstorybookui-options
// To find allowed options for getStorybookUI
const StorybookUIRoot = getStorybookUI({});

// If you are using React Native vanilla and after installation you don't see your app name here, write it manually.
// If you use Expo you should remove this line.
AppRegistry.registerComponent("%APP_NAME%", () => StorybookUIRoot);

export default StorybookUIRoot;
```

Add screenshot of `App.tsx`.

[image]

Comment: You might want to post some of your code. In the Storybook initialization, there should be some changes to your codebase. Can you post what changed and how? That would help folks answer your question more directly. 

Right now it looks like Storybook is "running", but maybe something in the components is misconfigured. Hard to say without more detail.

Comment: I don't add or modify any code, which file do you want to see?

Comment: If you're using git, you can run `git status` to check what changed in the initialization. Then check those files and maybe post one as an example. 

If nothing was changed, then maybe something went wrong with the Storybook initialization.

Comment: Do you have your device simulator running as well?

Comment: Hi @TylerWilliams, I also screenshot the file storybook generated. Did you tried the tutorial with no issue? I also run `expo build:iOS` won't solve it either. `expo start --ios` works fine.

Comment: Hmm, reading through the tutorial link, I see this: 

`All the code was intended for the Android platform, if you want to use IOS, some components might need to be updated in order to work properly.`

Maybe building for iOS is the problem here. Have you looked at the Android version?

Comment: It works right now~!!! I build android and come back with iOS, then it runs~?! I will double check later and see if it can be reproduced.

Comment: I tried to add an answer to this question but a mod deleted it for no reason?? Please check this issue on the repo https://github.com/storybookjs/react-native/issues/55

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to answer this once already but my answer was deleted for some reason. I know this issue very well since I'm the maintainer of the package so I don't see why this answer would not be valid.

This is a common issue. You can see some further details this pinned issue from the [repo](https://github.com/storybookjs/react-native/issues/55).

The problem here is the connection between the mobile storybook UI and the web storybook UI via websockets. In order to solve it you need to make sure that the right IP address is being used.

First you should make sure the ondeviceUI is loaded on your mobile device since the web UI gets the stories from the device.

If you are still having issues you can manually specify the port and ip address

First set the ip and port on the getStorybookUI call.

```
const StorybookUIRoot = getStorybookUI({
 host: "192.111.1.11", // replace this ip address with your local ip address
  port: "7007"
});
```

Then adjust the script used to launch the react-native-server to have the port and ip option. Make sure that you use exactly the same port and host that you used in the previous step otherwise it won't work.

It should look something like this but with your own IP address instead.

```
"storybook": "start-storybook -p 7007 -h 192.111.1.11"
```

Comment: I would like to add that for me it was enough to add `enableWebsockets: true` to the `getStorybookUI` call like so:

```
const StorybookUIRoot = getStorybookUI({
    enableWebsockets: true,
});
```

Comment: yes now since v6 is out websockets are disabled by default so you will need to enable them

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @TylerWilliams' hint.

It might due to an unknown bug on storybook, there isn't a complete solution yet, but build an android app could resolve the unlimited loading issue.

Answer (score 0):

If it still doesn't work after Danny's change, try removing your `yarn.lock` and running `yarn` again.